# Turn text with date to date type

Tags: excel, date, types, hour

I've searched on the internet and couldn't find. The only solution I found was to download kutools, and I can't do it.
I've made a macro that gets some values from an intranet, but I need the type of cell to be in date so I can work around it and filter it.

I don't know if I explained it correctly, and sorry if my english isn't the best.
I made an image to better explain it.

How it currently is / How  I want it to be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DATE` and `TIME` functions to convert your text to date/time format.

```
=DATE(2018,MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2))+TIME(MID(A2,7,2),RIGHT(A2,2),0)
```

[image]

Using Filters:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked to a certain point. I can use it in formulas, but I can't filter it as date. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure - I can't reproduce your situation. See additional screenshot.

Comment: at C2 put `=date(year(B2),month(b2),day(b2))`